# How to make an previous/back button with an arc4random function?

Tags: xcode, nsstring, plist, arc4random

I use arc4random in my project. Everything is fine with the functionality.

I want to add some more functionality, like a previous/back button with the arc4random function. I get my string out of an PLIST file and use it with the arc4random. When I touch the screen some random text will appear. I want to include an previous/back button so I can get the text (previous way) that was shown.

Anyone with an idea? Thanks a lot!

Edited:
With some code:

```
NSString *pathToQuestions = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Bee" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *questions = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathToQuestions] autorelease];

int questionIndex = arc4random() %[questions count];

NSDictionary *question = [questions objectAtIndex:questionIndex];
NSString *name = [question objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString *sub = [question objectForKey:@"sub"];

nameslbl.text = name;
subslbl.text = sub;
```

Comment: Without your code, this question makes no sense. Please post the relevant snippets showing how you are using `arc4random()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are generating random integers using `arc4random()`, then the only way for you to "go back" is if you store the output of the function. You can do with with an `NSMutableArray` easily enough. Each time you generate a new random index, add it to the end of the array. To go back, simply access the previous object in the array.

Comment: Hmmm.. that make sense.. Do you know a tutorial for this?